# Express/Heroku - Cookie set on server web app instead of client web app

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, cookies, cross-domain

I got this case where after deployment to Heroku, my cookies are not set to the client. When running localhost, the cookies are set as expected and its working, but after deployed to Heroku the cookies are set on the backend web app instead of the client (where I want it to be set).

The client is deployed as the first web app below, and the server as the later, so they are separated
[image: Separate client and server]

When I log on into the client after it has been deployed (react), the cookie is not set there but on the backend app instead. So the cookie is set successfully, but not to my client side.
[image]

Why are the cookies ending up here?! I want cookie on client
[image]

My express, cookie-parser, cors app looks like like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4040;
require("dotenv").config();

//connect to db
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_URI ||
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGODB_USER}:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@shopproject.xaroy.mongodb.net/shopitems?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }
);

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
  console.log("Connected to Mongodb");
});

//middleware

app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["https://gigvilla.herokuapp.com", "http://gigvilla.com"],
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: [
      "Content-Type",
      "Accept",
      "Origin",
      "X-Requested-With",
      "Authorization",
      "Set-Cookie",
    ],
  })
);

//http req logger
app.use(morgan("tiny"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.cookie("trol", "valle").send("hello");
});

//Getting routes to app
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const shopRoutes = require("./routes/shop");
const storeRoutes = require("./routes/store");
//below test

app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes);
app.use(storeRoutes);
// app.use(storeRoutes);
//test

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`server is running at ${PORT}`));
```

with the following snippet sending the cookie

```
exports.loginUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  //Validate
  const { error } = loginValidation(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  //Check for existing user
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email.toLowerCase() });
  if (!user) return res.status(400).send("Email does not exist");

  if (user.authenticated === false) return res.status(400).send("Not verified");

  //Password is correct
  const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
  if (!validPass) return res.status(400).send("Invalid password");

  //Create and assign JWT token
  const token = jwt.sign(
    { userId: user._id, userName: user.user },
    process.env.JWT_TOKEN_SECRET
  );
  res
    .status(202)
    .cookie("Authorization", "Bearer " + token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 3600000,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
    })
    .cookie("just testing", "my name is", {
      httpOnly: false,
      maxAge: 3600000,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
      path: "/",
    })
    .json({ userName: user.user });
};
```

Anyone know how to solve this? Getting very desperate at this point.. (16 hours in..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Herokuapp.com is included in the Mozilla Foundation’s Public Suffix List so it will prevent you from setting cookies on herokuapp.com or *.herokuapp.com. You can check the list [here](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat).

I recommend you hosting it on any other cloud provider which can help you to set cookies.

Also, you can check the [heroku dev center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com) why it is not allowed to set cookies. It might help you to understand the issue is not with the code, it is with the hosting.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I thought it was definitely my fault. This might then be why I have almost no hair left to tear then.. Do you think it would make a difference if I add a custom domain to the backend/server?

Comment: It seems at the first place that the issue is with the code, but it is not. You might need to check, it should work though as per the notes from heroku dev.

Comment: If the answer helps, you can accept and upvote it. thanks!

Comment: I tried deploying my front-end with Netlify this morning with the same issue happening. It is still setting a cookie on the backend web app, but nothing on the front-end, so this did not work. Did you mean the backend needs to be deployed to another site as well?

Comment: Yes, the backend needs to be deployed to other domain so that it can set the cookie to every response. Front-end just reads the cookie and append it to every request. Cookie is set by backend only, FE is the consumer.

Comment: Ok, I will try to deploy my server/backend to another provider. I tried with changing the domain to api.gigvilla.com for the backend, but this caused the same behavior. I'm a bit doubtful why cookies are set for the backend web application and not the client side...It seems like it's setting cookies, just not where I need them

Answer (score 1):

If you ever run in to this issue, it's a mix of what Apoorva kindly helped with above and adding your server side to a subdomain of the client's domain.

When both server and client were set to client : "customdomain.com" respectively server : api.customdomain.com, the cookie could then be set as:
.cookie("Authorization", "Bearer " + token, {
httpOnly: true,
maxAge: 3600000,
domain: "gigvilla.com",

```
  // below to be added when running on https
  // sameSite: "none",
  // secure: true,
})
```

the "domain" part made sure the cookie was set for client side as well.

Comment: Great, you find the solution!!