# Cookies not being sent to browser

Tags: heroku, cookies, http-headers, cross-domain, session-cookies

I have a full-stack project that I made with React and Express JS. Both are currently hosted in heroku as two different projects (frontend: `x.herokuapp.com`; backend: `y.herokuapp.com`).

Here's the problem. Whenever I try to log in to the app, the cookie is not being set on the browser. The cookie storage in the browser is empty, therefore the request fails. Where could the error be?

Here's the code that sets the session:

```
app.use(session({
  name: "irmp_session",
  secret: process.env.SESSION_KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  httpOnly: false,
  maxAge: 7200000, // 2 hrs validity
  store: MongoDBStore,
  cookie: {
    path: "/",
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'none'
  }
}))
```

And the frontend code that does the request:

```
const URL = 'https://y.herokuapp.com/';

const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
  },
  credentials: 'same-origin'
});

  fetchUserInformation() {
    return http.get("/users/profile", { withCredentials: true });
  }
```

Some articles I've read are pointing me to a CORS issue, but I don't know how to fix it really. Any leads are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because *.herokuapp.com is listed in the Public Suffix List, preventing you to set a cookie on the server side.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com

Related question:
[Express/Heroku - Cookie set on server web app instead of client web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68346707/express-heroku-cookie-set-on-server-web-app-instead-of-client-web-app)

Note that a custom domain will not have this problem, however you have to use a paid plan to get free SSL on custom domain

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, but please correct me if I am wrong. So to solve my problem, I need to buy a custom domain and use that instead of the standard `[backend-project-name].herokuapp.com`. With this, will I be able to surpass the issue? Do I need to get a hosting site or no need already? I'm sorry as I am still learning on this.

Comment: Yes, since a custom domain will not be in the public suffix list. You can simply host the frontend and backend on different subdomains, such as `customdomain.com` and `api.customdomain.com`.

But again, the free plan of heroku does not comes with free SSL (https) for custom domain, so if you are not comfortable with the $7/month per dyno, maybe look into other hosting providers.